# NSFetchedResultsController is blank while fetching from NSManagedObjectContext with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I am using UIDocument to access core data and trying to setup NSFetchedResultsController in a background thread not to block main UI.  It works if i use the uidocument's managedobjectcontext but not the child.  I took some of this code from one of the answers here at stack overflow but are not able to make it work with fetchedresultscontroller.

```
[ZH peopleDocumentusingBlock:^(UIManagedDocument *peopleDoc){
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        context.parentContext = peopleDoc.managedObjectContext;
        [context performBlock:^{
             NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
           request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"key" ascending:YES]];
            [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"imageurl.length>0"];
            request.predicate = predicate;

            NSError *error = nil;
            if(!self.totalNumberOfPeople) //set total number of people for this fetch used for show more records
            {
                self.totalNumberOfPeople = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error]; 
                NSLog(@"total number of people -> %d",self.totalNumberOfPeople);

            }

                self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"peopleCache"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.delegate refreshPeoplelTableview];
                    NSLog(@"fetched objects -> %d",[self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count]);
                    NSLog(@"total number of people -> %d",self.totalNumberOfPeople);


                });
    }];
}];
```

Actually `context countforfetchrequest` does but not fetcheresultscontroller.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a "semi-permanant" FRC (it is an instance variable of your controller), but setting it to use a "temporary" MOC, that will go away when no one is using it anymore.

I do not follow what you are really trying to do, but I would think if you store the "temporary" MOC, it will work.  Though, you then have to ask why you are doing all this in the first place.

Insert the code between parentContext and performBlock

```
    context.parentContext = peopleDoc.managedObjectContext;
    // Keep the MOC with the FRC...
    self.myBackgroundFetchingMoc = context;
    [context performBlock:^{
```

Comment: Jody thanks again for the reply! I am still in the middle of this app trying different things.  Basically here i am setting up a fetch request for a tableview and because i am using block i can't seem to put this in a dispatch queue because when i do queue release it crashes.  I wanted to use SPrivateQueueConcurrencyType to load the data and not freeze the ui.  I tried what you suggested but still same result.  countforfetch works but not nsfetchedresultscontroller it just hangs on init.

Comment: Also what i am doing instead of loading 2000 records at once i load 50 and when user scrolls to the end it reloads fetch request with another 50 records. At this point i couldn't get batch working so i am just increasing the fetch limit by 50 and reloading the whole NSFetchedResultsController  Is there a better way of setting up pagination for NSFetchedResultsController?  Thanks again!

Comment: I actually suggest you place the FRC on the main MOC of the UIManagedDocument.  You will have to manage the interaction between the background and the UI on the main thread.  You can setup the initial FRC, and then populate the MOC via a background fetch.  Also, you don't have to load all the records at once.  2000 is not very big and certainly within the realm of FRC to handle easily.